# I do not understand how to use ranked-model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sortedlist

I'm using the gem ranked model : https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model

I want to use it to allow my users to order articles in a back office.

From what i understand from the gem the stored value in DB is different from the _position who is the real rank if you start counting your elements.

Now if i have an array of images, i display them and i want to increase or decrease their position of one rank. i would do a row_order_postion +1 or -1. But i cannot know their row_order_postion (it returns nil), only their row_order.

My question is : what use is there to be able to change by row_order_position if i cannot know my row_order_position ?

Answer (score 0):

I too find this a little weird, but if you are iterating over an array, one work-around is to do a `each_with_index`. This way you can store the position somewhere (in a hidden field for instance), and when performing the rearrangement of the articles pass the new position + or - 1.

```
# Something like this
<% Article.each_with_index do |article, index| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'article', :locals => {:article => article, :position => index} %> 
<% end %>
```